# SPDY protocol support from Android browser?

Tags: android, http, protocols, spdy

I wonder if Android browser supports Google's new SPDY protocol?
I can find SPDY comments from Android's Chromium source codes, but I can't sure if it's fully implemented.

If it's enabled, I want to compare normal HTTP vs SPDY performance with Smart Phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chrome for Android](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/android/) supports SPDY.

Amazon's Silk is also using SPDY, but the connection itself is proxied through Amazon's SPDY servers, so that's a slightly different use case.

Answer (score 2):

Android Browser since Honeycomb supports SPDY/2.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting timing - Google released benchmarks for SPDY on mobile devices today.

https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/spdy-for-mobile

Comment: The article is really badly named - "SPDY Performance on Mobile Networks" - there was no mobile network involved, it was all simulated...